# PIG doesn't read my custom InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I have a custom `MyInputFormat` that suppose to deal with record boundary problem for [multi-lined inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871134/pig-udf-handle-multi-lined-tuple-split-into-different-mapper). But when I put the `MyInputFormat` into my UDF load function. As follow:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
public class EccUDFLogLoader extends LoadFunc {
    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() {
        System.out.println("I am in getInputFormat function");
        return new MyInputFormat();
    }
}

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
public class MyInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit inputSplit, JobConf jobConf) throws IOException {
        System.out.prinln("I am in createRecordReader");
        //MyRecordReader suppose to handle record boundary
        return new MyRecordReader((FileSplit)inputSplit, jobConf);
    }
}
```

For each mapper, it print out `I am in getInputFormat function` but not `I am in createRecordReader`. I am wondering if anyone can provide a hint on how to hoop up my costome MyInputFormat to PIG's UDF loader? Much Thanks.

I am using PIG on Amazon EMR.

Comment: try adding an `@Override` annotation on the `createRecordReader` method to ensure you have the correct signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature doesn't match that of the parent class (you're missing the Reporter argument), try this:

```
@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> getRecordReader(
        InputSplit inputSplit, JobConf jobConf, Reporter reporter)
             throws IOException {
  System.out.prinln("I am in createRecordReader");
  //MyRecordReader suppose to handle record boundary
  return new MyRecordReader((FileSplit)inputSplit, jobConf);
}
```

**EDIT** Sorry i didn't spot this earlier, as you note, you need to use the new API signature instead:

```
@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> 
      createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
             TaskAttemptContext context) {
  System.out.prinln("I am in createRecordReader");
  //MyRecordReader suppose to handle record boundary
  return new MyRecordReader((FileSplit)inputSplit, jobConf);
}
```

And your MyRecordReader class needs to extend the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader` class

Comment: if I put @Override, then it gives me error says `MyInputFormat.java:11: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @Override.`

Comment: The error is because your current methof signature doesn't override a parent method. Add in the Reporter argument and you should be ok

Comment: Pig `getInputFormat` expect a `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` so the `TextInputFormat` in `MyInputFormat` is from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat`. And it doesn't have `getRecordReader` but `createRecordReader`. That's why I use `createRecordReader`. And it still gives me error.

Comment: Or should I not extends `TextInputFormat`? If so which one should I extend to??

Comment: You should extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

Comment: Thanks, I am be able to reach my `RecordReader` now. Thanks `Chris` and `zjffdu`